# DES Decryption in SQL CLR Scalar UDF not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, cryptography, sqlclr, des

We have a **legacy** application that uses SQL Server as its back-end. As part of some security concerns, it encrypts some fields collected from the user using (single) DES with a key & IV that is hard-coded into the app code, then Base64 encodes the encrypted bytes, and finally stores that string in a varchar column in the DB. Woefully insecure at this point (and probably when it was first coded), along with a questionable design / implementation, but it is what it is. My task is to implement a CLR User Defined Scalar Function in SQL Server that can decrypt this type of data.

As a proof of concept, I created the following short console app to make sure I understand the DES decryption process in C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class My_Decrypt
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] IV = BitConverter.GetBytes(0xFECAEFBEEDFECEFA);
        byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password");

        foreach (string cipherText in args)
        {
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            MemoryStream es = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(
                es,
                des.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read
            );
            byte[] plainBytes = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];
            cs.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            string plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plainBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "'{0}' == '{1}'\nusing key = '{2}', IV = '{3}'\ndecrypts to '{4}' == '{5}'.\n",
                cipherText,
                BitConverter.ToString(cipherBytes),
                BitConverter.ToString(Key),
                BitConverter.ToString(IV),
                BitConverter.ToString(plainBytes),
                plainText
            );
        }
    }
}
```

After compiling, I am able to run the following:

```
C:\>My_Decrypt.exe KDdSnfYYnMQawhwuaWo2WA==
'KDdSnfYYnMQawhwuaWo2WA==' == '28-37-52-9D-F6-18-9C-C4-1A-C2-1C-2E-69-6A-36-58'
using key = '70-61-73-73-77-6F-72-64', IV = 'FA-CE-FE-ED-BE-EF-CA-FE'
decrypts to '73-65-63-72-65-74-20-64-61-74-61-00-00-00-00-00' == 'secret data     '.
```

Which looks correct and I verified using **openssl**.

So, having established that, I next tried to use the same code in a CLR scalar UDF as follows:

```cs
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
    public static SqlString DES_Decrypt( SqlString CipherText, SqlBinary DES_Key, SqlBinary DES_IV )
    {
        if (CipherText.IsNull || DES_Key.IsNull || DES_IV.IsNull)
            return SqlString.Null;
        string cipherText = CipherText.ToString();
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        MemoryStream es = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes);
        DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] IV = (byte[]) DES_IV;
        byte[] Key = (byte[]) DES_Key;
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(
            es, des.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read );
        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];
        cs.Read(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        cs.Close();
        string plainText = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(plainBytes);
        return new SqlString(plainText);
    }
```

However, after compiling, loading the assembly into MSSQL, creating the function, and trying to execute it -- I get garbage for the output. So, after many attempts to get this work (which included creating the POC app above), I replaced the `return` in the last line with the following:

```cs
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(
            "\n'{0}' == '{1}'\nusing key = '{2}', IV = '{3}'\ndecrypts to '{4}' == '{5}'.",
            cipherText,
            BitConverter.ToString(cipherBytes),
            BitConverter.ToString(Key),
            BitConverter.ToString(IV),
            BitConverter.ToString(plainBytes),
            plainText
        ));
```

Now, when I run in MSSQL the query `SELECT dbo.DES_Decrypt(N'KDdSnfYYnMQawhwuaWo2WA==', CAST('password' AS binary(8)), 0xFACEFEEDBEEFCAFE);`, I get the exception error message:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "DES_Decrypt": 
System.ArgumentException: 
'KDdSnfYYnMQawhwuaWo2WA==' == '28-37-52-9D-F6-18-9C-C4-1A-C2-1C-2E-69-6A-36-58'
using key = '70-61-73-73-77-6F-72-64', IV = 'FA-CE-FE-ED-BE-EF-CA-FE'
decrypts to '47-F7-06-E4-88-C4-50-5B-E5-4D-CC-C9-32-C7-8F-BB' == 'G????P[?M??2???'.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at DES_Decryptor.Decrypt(SqlString CipherText, SqlBinary DES_Key, SqlBinary DES_IV)
.
```

The input processing looks good: the base64 decoded bytes match, as do the binary versions of the Key & IV that are passed in. So, it seems to me that something is going wrong in the C# DES decryption routine when it's called from the CLR scalar UDF, but I'm frustrated and all out of ideas. Any clues as to what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You probably already know this, but that security scheme isn't useful against a motivated attacker (between the use of DES and the hardcoded key).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica - yes, I thought I made that clear in the intro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing your results in both places and changing several things yet not changing the output, I went over both sets of code making sure they were the same and found the issue:

In the call to `new CryptoStream()`, you are using `des.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV)` in the console app (correct), but using `des.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV)` in the SQLCLR function (different and incorrect). Changing the SQLCLR function to instead use `des.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV)` results in the expected output.

Some general notes regarding the code:

1. You should use the `Value` property of the `Sql*` types (i.e. the input parameters) instead of calling `ToString()` or casting. For example:

   ```cs
   string cipherText = CipherText.Value;
   byte[] IV = DES_IV.Value;
   byte[] Key = DES_Key.Value;
   ```
2. You should wrap the instantiations of `MemoryStream`, `DESCryptoServiceProvider`, `CryptoStream` in `using()` blocks so that the external resources are properly cleaned up. All 3 of those implement the IDisposable interface.
3. Since a `NULL` passed in for any of the 3 input parameters will return a `NULL`, you can bypass needing to handle that in the code by setting an option when creating the T-SQL wrapper function. Of course, this cannot be automated via the SSDT / Visual Studio Publish operation, but you can either handle the deployment manually in which case you issue the `CREATE FUNCTION` yourself, or you can add a post-release deployment script to execute an `ALTER FUNCTION`. So, remove this from the code:

   ```cs
   if (CipherText.IsNull || DES_Key.IsNull || DES_IV.IsNull)
       return SqlString.Null;
   ```

   and add the following to a post release rollout SQL script (SSDT / Visual Studio will handle that, at least):

   ```sql
   ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DES_Decrypt](
       @CipherText [nvarchar](max),
       @DES_Key    [varbinary](8000),
       @DES_IV [varbinary](8000)
   )
   RETURNS [nvarchar](max)
   WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
   AS EXTERNAL NAME [YourAssembly].[YourClass].[DES_Decrypt];
   ```

   The `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` option in the `WITH` clause does the magic ;-). The more `NULL`s you get the more efficient this becomes as SQL Server doesn't need to call the code given it already knows the answer. Just keep in mind that this option returns a `NULL` if *any* input is `NULL`, so if any input params are expected to pass in a `NULL`, then this option won't work.

---

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit my site: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)